# Return of api rest with node

Tags: node.js, odoo, nestjs, xml-rpc

Im trying to generate rest-api for Odoo - ERP whith Nestjs and odoo-xmlrpc. I can connect to odoo but i cant respose the values than odoo response to my service.

This is the odoo service that response a value or an error:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
@Injectable()
export class OdooService  {
    private Odoo = require('odoo-xmlrpc');
    public odoo;
    constructor () {
        this.odoo = new this.Odoo({
            url: 'https:/www.xxxxxxxxx.xxx',
            db: 'xxxx',
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password'
        });
    }

    execute(model: string, funtion: string , params: any[], callback) {
        const odoo = new this.Odoo({
            url: 'https:/www.xxxxxxxxx.xxx',
            db: 'xxxx',
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password'
        });
        odoo.connect(async function (error: any): Promise<any> {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error); 
                return [{}];
            }
            odoo.execute_kw(model, funtion, params, function (error: any, values: []) {
               if (error) { 
                   console.log('error :>> ', error);
                   return [{}];
               }
               callback(values);
            })

        })
    }
}
```

this is the service that use the odooServive

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { OdooService } from '../odoo/odoo.service';
import { CreateCountryDto } from './dto/create-country.dto';
import { UpdateCountryDto } from './dto/update-country.dto';

@Injectable()
export class CountriesService {
  constructor(
    private odooService: OdooService
) {}

  async findAll() {
     return await this.odooService.execute('res.country', 'search_read', [[[]], { fields: ['name'] }], async function (response: []) {
      //  console.log(response);
       return  await response;
     });
  }

}
```

odoo documentation: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/webservices/odoo.html
library documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo-xmlrpc

Comment: You are confusing methods that use callbacks with promises. Nothing shown is using promises which makes all your `await` and `async` useless. Also a `return` in a callback does not return to the outer function. You either need to refactor all this to promisify it or use standard callback approaches

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating @charlietfl's comment into an answer, you can use one of these codes, either using callback, or using async await

**No Promise, no callback**

```js
findAll() {
  return this.odooService.execute('res.country', 'search_read', [[[]], { fields: ['name'] }]);
}
```

**Using callback, no need for Promise**

```js
findAll() {
  this.odooService.execute('res.country', 'search_read', [[[]], { fields: ['name'] }], function (response: []) {
    return response;
  });
}
```

**Using Promise**

```js
async findAll() {
  const response = await this.odooService.execute('res.country', 'search_read', [[[]], { fields: ['name'] }]);

  return response;  
}
```